# R: avoiding loops while inserting records into a matrix

Tags: r

**I have a matrix m of zeros and a data-frame df containing records I want to insert into m.**

```
# fix seed -------------------------------------------
set.seed(0)    

# create m, matrix of zeros --------------------------
rnames <- seq( 1, 100, 1 )
m <- matrix( 0, length( rnames ), length( letters ),
      dimnames=list( rnames, letters ))

# create df of random records ------------------------
r <- sample( rnames, 10, replace=TRUE )
c <- sample( letters, 10, replace=TRUE )
q <- runif( 10, -10, 10 )
df <- data.frame( r, c, q )

# want to insert df$q at r,c in m --------------------
```

*Can I do this without resorting to a loop?  What is the cleanest approach?*

Comment: To make this reproducible, you should set a seed value anywhere prior to your first `sample`, e.g. `set.seed(0)`.

Comment: @iterator good idea - will edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass a matrix of indicies into `m`.

```
index <- cbind(
    row = df$r,
    col = match(df$c, colnames(m))       
)

m[index] <- df$q
```

Comment: (+1) That's the way to go. (I should have tested my solution before posting :)